# Calculating relative growth rate in R or excel

Tags: r, excel

I'm currently trying to work out the relative growth rate of individuals using the equation RGR = (lnW2-lnW1)/(t2-t1) so log of weight at time 2 minus log weight at time 1 divided by time 2-time 1.

Most individuals were measured 4 times so I'd use the 1st and 4th measure, however not all were so some were measured 3 times and others 2.

Just wondering if there is an easy way in either excel or R to work this out?

This is a rough example of the layout of the data (not the actual data as I do not have access to it at this time:

```
ID Replicate Mass Length Date
1  1         0.85  1.23  16/11/15
1  2         1.00  1.24  23/11/15
1  3         0.76  0.98  30/11/15
1  4         1.40  2.00  07/12/15
2  1         2.30  2.56  16/11/15
2  2         0.89  1.03  23/11/15
2  3         0.99  1.07  30/11/15
3  1         0.88  1.23  16/11/15
3  2         1.20  1.09  23/11/15
3  3         1.22  1.45  30/11/15
```

I have 90 individuals to work this out for so am looking for a quicker way rather than doing it manually! Thank you

Comment: Where is the time field? Replica=1s ??

Comment: So dates are sorted along with replica number right?

Comment: Yes they are e.g. all replicate 1s are 16/11/15, all 2s are 23/11/15 etc, but not each individual was measured 4 times

Comment: Are the data shown realistic or did you make them up as an illustration?  They are so extraordinarily variable over time that they suggest your proposed methods need to be improved to exploit all the information in each set of replicates rather than using just the first and last observations.

Comment: They are just an illustration

Answer (score 1):

```
rgr <- function(data, replicate, Id, cval){
df <- data.frame(ID = unique(data[,Id]))
df$Growth <- NA
uniquelist <- unique(data[,Id])
      for(i in uniquelist){
       max = data[data[,replicate] == max(data[data[,Id] == i, replicate]), cval]
       min = data[data[,replicate] == min(data[data[,Id] == i, replicate]), cval]
        growth = (log(max)- log(min)) / (max - min)
       df[df$ID == i,"Growth"] <- growth
            }
    return(df)
}
```

Assuming replicate is the number of the trial. Id is the unique id of each individual and cval is the variable for the growth you want to calculate.